# Java : Instruction Flow not clear

Tags: java

I was going through some random java code and came across this peice of code, I am trying to understand the flow and having hard time understanding how the actual implementation of the class, actual operation done by the class so my basic questions is `WhatDoIDo` class actually do ? Any guidance would be apprecaited.

***Q:***
What would be the unit test case which explains the improved performance because of implementing in the concurrent environment.

***Code***

```
public class WhatDoIDo{
    private X x;
    private boolean b;
    private Object o;

    public WhatDoIDo(X x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    synchronized Object z() {
        if (!b) {
            o = x.y();
            b = true;
        }
        return o;
    }

    public interface X {
        Object y();
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I improve the performance of it using concurrency package ? or in other words how can I make a method open for concurrent access without making it synchronized ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WhatDoIDo` is a wrapper class that wraps an object `o`.

It defines an inner `interface X` which has a method `y()` to create an `Object`. This interface can be thought of as a strategy for creating the object. When an object of `WhatDoIDo` is created using `new`, it's constructor is supplied with an object of `X` that will be used to create the object.

It creates the wrapped object and makes it available to client code through `z()` method. It creates the object lazily. It uses a `boolean` flag `b` to keep track of whether the object has been created or not. When `z()` is called by client to get hold of the wrapped object, if the flag is set, the object `o` is returned. If flag is not set, an object is created using the strategy `X` supplied when creating this `WhatDoIDo` object. A reference to the created object is stored and returned to the client. Also, `z()` is `synchronized` since it creates the object if it has not been created already. If it was not synchronized, two threads could end up creating an object each and only one of them will get stored.

```
public class ObjectWrapper {
    private CreationStrategy strategy;
    private boolean objectCreated;
    private Object wrappedObject;

    public ObjectWrapper(CreationStrategy strategy) {
        this.strategy = strategy;
    }

    synchronized Object getWrappedObject() {
        if (!objectCreated) {
            wrappedObject = strategy.createObject();
            objectCreated = true;
        }
        return wrappedObject;
    }

    public interface CreationStrategy {
        Object createObject();
    }
}
```

Comment: How can we Implement the test cases for the checking the improvement in performance ?

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be simple memoization:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization

Comment: Can it also be related to Static mechanism or lazy loading ?

Answer (score 0):

```
synchronized Object z() {
    if (!b) {
        o = x.y();
        b = true;
    }
    return o;
}
```

This is a method with *default* visibility (package visible). It returns an object
of type Object. It's signature contains the *synchronized* keyword. This instructs the
compiler to disallow multiple threads to execute this method at the same time. If one thread executes the method, the method is *locked*, or *synchronized*. Other threads may not execute the method until the original thread released this implicit locking.

In short, the synchronized keyword is a [semaphore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)) mechanism built into Java. (Actually, on second thought, is this keyword actually a semaphore?)

Comment: Can you elaborate on the flow of the instructions 
?

Comment: If the boolean field "b" is false, the object "o" is assigned the result of the method "y", bounded to object "x". "b" is then assigned the value "true", and "o" is returned.

Comment: thanks Mike for the internal flow but I am trying to understand the complete flow of the class and what is that this class is actually doing ?

Comment: Oh. You got me there. I guess it all depends on your implementation of interface "X". I guess on the first execution of method "Z" only, o is assigned a new value. After that is complete, "o"'s value doesn't appear to change.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Mike says.
The default initialization for a boolean is false (For integers, floats and doubles 0 - Objects are set to null).
What the method does is the first time it is called it will return whatever Object Y is in the X that was passed into the constructor, After that it will return the same thing since o is assigned to x.y().

Is this homework ?

Comment: No. I found it on some java code questions and wanted to solve it but was having hard time solving it.

Comment: and why do you say that Romain ? I am just trying to get as much as I can from this excercise, also is there a way I can use some concurrency packages to optimize this approach ?

Comment: @Rachel It is just poor convoluted code, that does not seem to achieve much. It is not commented, variable names have no meaning. The concurrency aspect is incidental here, it does not matter at all for the code being shown. Everybody should know how to read and understand other people's code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the WhatDoIDo class is like a wrapper around a class that implements interface X.  The first time z is called, it sets the object it's going to return, and sets b to true, so that even if x.y() returns null, x.y() doesn't get called again.

That way, repeatedly calling z() will return the same object (or null value).

Comment: Is there any reason to have something like this in place ?

Comment: Is there a way I can optimize the performance of it using concurrency package ?

Comment: It's an optimization to avoid having to call x.y() over and over again if it's expensive.